# Integral of the product of spherical harmonics and derivatives of spherical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

What is the Integral of the product of spherical harmonics and derivatives of  spherical harmonics? More precisely, I am looking for 
$$\int_\Omega d\Omega\, Y_{l}^m Y_{l^\prime}^{m^\prime} \partial_\theta Y_{l^{\prime\prime}}^{m^{\prime\prime}}$$
and 
$$\int_\Omega d\Omega\, Y_{l}^m \partial_\theta Y_{l^\prime}^{m^\prime} \partial_\theta Y_{l^{\prime\prime}}^{m^{\prime\prime}}$$